# Pre populate database in KMM on iOS side using SQLDelight

Tags: ios, database, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I want to pre-populate the database in my KMM project. I’m using SQLDelight.
I have this implementation for the Android side.

```
actual fun Scope.createDriver(): SqlDriver {

    val context = androidContext()
    val fileName = "dbFileName"
    val database: File = context.getDatabasePath(fileName)

    if (!database.exists()) {
        val inputStream = context.assets.open(fileName)
        val outputStream = FileOutputStream(database.absolutePath)

        inputStream.use { input ->
            outputStream.use {
                input.copyTo(it)
            }
        }
    }

    return AndroidSqliteDriver(NoteDatabase.Schema, context, fileName)
}
```

I tried this code on iOS but it’s not working.

```
val path = "test.db"
val fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager

if (!fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {
    val bundlePath = MR.assets.balagh_ul_quran.url.path.toString()
    fileManager.copyItemAtPath(bundlePath, toPath = path, error = null)

}

return NativeSqliteDriver(NoteDatabase.Schema, path)
```

Can anyone suggest something?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
val path = "test.db"
val dbFile = File(DatabaseFileContext.databasePath(path, null))
```

Try that. `DatabaseFileContext` is a sqliter classe, just FYI.

Comment: Thank you for the input, can you please explain a little bit..

Comment: "dbFile" is the path. You need to copy your db files to that. Your question seemed to be about finding where the db should go.

Comment: There’s no any File class which accepts parameter like this but instead FILE which accepts object of NativePtr.

Actually I’m able to pre-populate db on Android side but nothing found regarding iOS.